# Spinner de texto con PHP (sustitución de términos en un texto)

Tags: php, spinner

Una consulta tengo un spiner en PHP. El problema es que algunas palabras no sé el porqué lo saca así.

Os dejo código y resultado:

```
<?php
$cadena = $_POST["texto"];//Aquí recojo el texto de un form.

$healthy = array("boda","advertí"....);

$yummy   = array("casamiento","avisar"...);

$newphrase = str_replace($healthy, $yummy, $cadena,$contador);

echo $newphrase;
```

[image: Captura de pantalla del resultado esperado]

Answer (score 3):

Pues lo que pasa es que **tu spinner está en pañales** todavía. Hace falta mejorarlo mucho. seguro que uno de los términos que reemplazas es "rico" (o "ricos") por "adinerado" (o "adinerados").

Entonces, eléct**rico**s te lo cambia por eléct**adinerado**s.

Te lo tienes que currar mucho más para hacer un spinner en condiciones.

Lo primero que tienes que hacer es pensar toda la casuística. Lo más obvio, es que tienes que reemplazar palabras enteras, por lo que deberás buscar cada término con espacio delante y espacio detrás. Pero pudiera ser que el término estuviera al inicio del texto, entonces tienes que mirar si el texto empieza por el término y un espacio. O pudiera ser que estuviera al final, entonces hay que mirar si el texto termina en espacio y el término. Luego, tienes que considerar que en vez de espacio al final puede ser espacio, o coma, o punto, o punto y coma. De otros caracteres en principio puedes pasar. Y ahora, para terminar de complicarlo todo, ten en cuenta las mayúsculas. Al menos cuando el término vaya al inicio del texto, o después de punto, debes ponerlo en mayúscula.

Una vez pensado todo eso, es hora de implementarlo en código. Puedes seguir usando str_replace() y otras funciones de manejo de cadenas, como mb_substr(), mb_strpos(),... Esto es trabajoso pero se puede decir que tienes claro lo que vas haciendo. Pero también puedes usar reemplazos mediante expresiones regulares, con preg_replace().

Si quieres, empieza por lo de buscar con espacio delante y detrás, y luego lo vas "complicando".

```
$healthy = array("boda","advertí"....);
$yummy   = array("casamiento","avisar"...);

$newphrase = $cadena;

$endings = [' ', ',', ';', '.'];

//Dando por sentado que $healthy y $yummy
//tienen el mismo número de elementos y se corresponden
foreach ($healthy as $key=>$strA) {
    //En medio del texto
    foreach ($endings as $ending) {
        $newphrase = str_replace(' '.$strA.$ending, ' '.$yummy[$key].$ending, $newphrase);
    }

    //TODO: Al inicio del texto

    //TODO: Al final del texto
}

echo $newphrase;
```

Bueno, te lo he dejado preparado también para cuando el término va seguido de coma, o punto y coma, o punto (además de espacio). Son los caracteres que he definido en $endings.

Lo demás, es ir jugando con las cadenas. O aprender bien sobre expresiones regulares.

Ah, más a tener en cuenta: el género. Si reemplazas "boda" por "casamiento", entonces esta frase:

"Voy a la boda de mi amigo"

Se quedará así:

"Voy a la casamiento de mi amigo"

Como ves, cuanto más piensas más se complica. Si quieres hacer el spinner por gusto, genial, si lo quieres hacer para venderlo, genial también, pero si lo quieres hacer porque lo necesitas para un proyecto o algo, quizá la solución más inteligente sea utilizar un servicio ya existente y muy currado como Espinner, un spinner de texto en español (en inglés hay muchos, pero éste es el primero que apareció para español) http://espinner.net/

Comment: Hola Jose, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Como puedo mejorarlo mejor si en definitiva tengo variable que obtengo el texto del form y 2 dos arrays no se como empezar para mejorarlo.

Comment: Hola, he ampliado mi respuesta para explicarte, y he añadido un ejemplo de código que para empezar te irá bastante bien.

Answer (score 3):

Tu código está reemplazando secuencia de caracteres literales por una sustitución sin tener en cuenta el límite de palabras.

Esto puede conseguirse con expresiones regulares con [`preg_replace()`](https://php.net/es/preg-replace) con la ayuda del [código de escape de límite de palabra `\b`](https://php.net/es/regexp.reference.escape) como te muestro a continuación:

```
<?php
$cadena = "eléctricos junkers ricos rico";

$healthy = [
    "boda",
    "advertí",
    "rico",
];

$healthy2 = [
    "/\bboda\b/i",
    "/\badvertí\b/i",
    "/\brico\b/i",
];

$yummy = [
    "casamiento",
    "avisar",
    "adinerado"
];

echo str_replace($healthy, $yummy, $cadena), PHP_EOL;
echo preg_replace($healthy2, $yummy, $cadena), PHP_EOL;
```

El resultado de la ejecución sería:

```
eléctadinerados junkers adinerados adinerado
eléctricos junkers ricos adinerado
```

Puedes ver el funcionamiento en línea en el siguiente enlace:

- http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ab04a9dcc15c88dac9312da93b94a0087e278209

En el caso de `rico` la expresión regular es `/\brico\b/` porque:

- `/`: los delimitadores `/` marcan el comienzo y el final de la expresión regular ([se pueden usar otros delimitadores](https://php.net/es/regexp.reference.delimiters)).
- `\b`: marca el límite de una palabra (en este caso, el comienzo).
- `rico`: debe seguirle la secuencia de caracteres `rico`.
- `\b`: marca el límite de una palabra (en este caso, el final).
- `/`: delimitador de final de expresión regular.

Comment: Muchas gracias a los que me habéis contestado, he podido enfocar mejor la solución. Voy a leer bien detalladamente que me habéis escrito para poder ar solución. Muchas gracias de verdad. Saludos.